# Is there anyway to Update UI when receiving Firebase notification

Tags: ios, swift4, firebase-notifications

I want to send an event to a UIViewController to Update Data when a Firebase Push notification is sent to reload Tableview content

I've set the whole Configuration and receiving the notification

any ideas or tutorial would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1). You will get a notification in didreceivenotification method for more info please refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428430-application). once you got a notification in didreceivenotification method get your view controller from the navigation stack or you can also set notification observer in that controller and post notification from didreceivenotification.